# How to prevent overlapping events using Linq + Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I'm wondering if anyone can help me? I'm trying to prevent events from overlapping in a room booking system. Each event has a start date/time and an end date/time. What I want to happen is if a user tries to book an event between times that already exist for an event it should error.

So for example the following should error as they overlap:-

```
Event 1:
- Start Date/Time: 10/08/2012 09:00
- End Date/Time: 10/08/2012 11:00

Event 2:
- Start Date/Time: 10/08/2012 10:00
- End Date/Time: 10/08/2012 12:00
```

I'm using MVC and Entity Framework, so a Linq solution would be preferable.

Any help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4446112/search-for-interval-overlap-in-list-of-intervals for solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean something like this:

```
new List<Event>()
{
    new Event() { StartsAt = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-1), EndsAt = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1) } 
};

Event newEvent = new Event() { StartsAt = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-3), EndsAt = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-2) };
bool newEventBookable = !existingsEvents.Any(x => x.StartsAt <= newEvent.EndsAt && x.EndsAt >= newEvent.StartsAt);
```

You can then just throw an error if newEventBookable is false.

I think this logic is OK for prior, subsequent, overlapping and contained events - but I'll soon find out if it it's not!

Comment: Thank you thats exactly what i was after :)

Comment: Agrees with http://stackoverflow.com/a/2368885/610832, though I find yours easier to follow.

Comment: I wanted to allow back-to-back appointments, so I changed `<=` and `>=` to only `<` and `>`